# How to maximize this function?

Tags: probability, statistics

The function is $lik(\theta)=\theta^n\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{-2}$ where $\theta<x<\infty$

I am getting $0$ if I just take the derivative of the log of this function. I believe this has to do with the domain of x being dependent on $\theta$?

Comment: You cannot take the derivative because $\theta$ is on the boundary.

Comment: Think about $\text{min}(x_1,...,x_n)$...

Comment: Is $\theta$ fixed?  Are there any restrictions on its value?

Comment: @Learner Given this is $\theta /something$, by maximizing $\theta$ I can probably ignore the denominator, and the maximum the numerator can go is min(x) due to the domain restriction?

Comment: @muzzlator I don't think there's a restiction on $\theta$, only that its less than x.

Comment: @Student1121 I just mean can we suppose $\theta > 0$?

Comment: @muzzlator My question did not specify a lower bound on $\theta$.

Comment: @muzzlator Thanks, I almost forgot the other conditions.

Comment: @Student1121  Look at these separate cases:  $\theta$ negative, $n$ odd and $n$ even.  $\theta = 0$.  $\theta > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the inequality should be $\theta \lt \min_i x_i \lt \infty$

This is not a well posed question.  Where do the $x_i$ come from?  If they are fixed, the product is a constant and you can just maximize over $\theta$, which is achieved if $\theta=\min x_i$.  If they are chosen after $\theta$, you need to specify how they are chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Your likelihood is

$lik(\theta) = \theta^n \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{-2} I\{x_i \in (\theta,\infty)\}$

If you put the $\theta$ and the $x_i$'s on the real line, you will verify that

$I\{x_i \in (\theta, \infty) \} =$  $I\{\theta \in (-\infty, min(x_i))\}$

for any sequence of $x_i$'s.

Plotting the $lik(\theta)$ versus $\theta$ you can determine the supreme of $lik(\theta)$.

If n is odd, the supreme of $lik(\theta)$ is $min(x_i)$, the maximum likelihood estimate. If n is even, maybe there is a restriction for the parameter space missed!