# What is the sufficient statistic for this function?

Tags: statistics

$f(x)=\theta/x^2$ where $\theta<x<\infty$

Given that the likelihood is $lik(\theta)=\theta^n \prod x_i^{-2}$

It seems to me that $T(X)=\prod x_i^{2}$ is the sufficient statistic, but intuitively, I think it should be $T(X)=\min(x_1...x_n)$

Comment: for a start sufficient statitics is not unique. $(x_1,... x_n)$ is always sufficient.

Comment: @Lost1 I see. Can you give me hints to why $min(x_1...x_n)$ is also sufficient? I know it's the MLE for $\theta$, but I don't know how I would go about getting it through the factorization theorem.

Comment: I seems you are applying the factorization to the mere formula, forgetting the domain. Have you studied  the simpler case of the uniform ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Uniform_distribution

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to maximize this function?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360038/how-to-maximize-this-function)

Answer (score 2):

well your distribution function is

$f(x)=\dfrac{\theta}{x^2} \mathbb{1}_{\{x>\theta\}}$

so your likelihood is

$\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\theta}{x_i^2} \mathbb{1}_{\{x_i>\theta\}}$

Fisher's factorisation criterion says $l(\theta|x) = h(x) g_\theta(T(x))$ then T(x) is a sufficient statistic.

instead of what you wrote down, $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{x_i^2}$ looks like $h(x)$

what you have left is the product of the indicator function is $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\theta\mathbb{1}_{\{x_i>\theta\}}$, well how can you write that using min?

EDIT: It is a common error to forget the indicator function. This is very very important, especially when the range of the distribution is dependent on the parameter.

Comment: I have not learned about indicator function in class, from reading the Wikipedia article it seems to indicate the range of the parameter in the function? Since $x_{i=1}^n>\theta$ I can rewrite it as $\prod \theta 1_{min(x_i)>\theta}$?

Comment: @student  $\theta^n 1_{\{\min(x_i)>\theta\}}$, yes. indicator means it is 1 where it has mass, 0 otherwise. For $x_i<\theta$, the likelihood should be 0, because by the way our distribution is defined, this it is not possible to observe daata with any $x_i<\theta$.

Comment: @Student1121 now using fisher criterion, this is clear, $\min(x_i)$ is sufficient statistics. job done. I am going to upvote your question because you actually solved it yourself.

Comment: From $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\theta^n}{x_i^2}$.$1$ why can't it directly be said that this is sufficient?Because $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\theta^n}{x_i^2}$ can be considered as $g(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n {x_i^2},\theta)$ and h(x) =1?Thus the function is factorized isn't it?Why is it necessary to have a indicator function

Comment: Then $T(X)=\prod x_i^{2}$ is a sufficient statistic

Comment: the pdf is wrong without the indicator. when $x_i<\theta$, then the likelihood should be 0, because observing such data would be impossible. note that sufficient statistics are not unique. $(x_1,...x_n)$ is always sufficient and so are order statistics for independent samples.